# When doing an "update-database" on the package manager console in visual studio i get error : Could not find content root folder

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, package-manager-console

So after adding a new migration in the package manager console in visual studio 2017 and doing the `Update-database` command, I get the following error:

> Could not find content root folder!

The issue seems to be that somehow the entity framework dbcontext is not connected to any DB.

If I run the `Get-Dbcontext` command I get the same error. Where or how is this linked?

```
public class ......DbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, ..........DbContext>, IAbpPersistedGrantDbContext
{
    /* Define an IDbSet for each entity of the application */

    public virtual DbSet<BinaryObject> BinaryObjects { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Friendship> Friendships { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<SubscribableEdition> SubscribableEditions { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<SubscriptionPayment> SubscriptionPayments { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<PersistedGrantEntity> PersistedGrants { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }

    public FutureAthletesDbContext(DbContextOptions<FutureAthletesDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BinaryObject>(b =>
        {
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ChatMessage>(b =>
        {
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.UserId, e.ReadState });
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.TargetUserId, e.ReadState });
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TargetTenantId, e.TargetUserId, e.ReadState });
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TargetTenantId, e.UserId, e.ReadState });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>(b =>
        {
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.UserId });
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.FriendUserId });
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.FriendTenantId, e.UserId });
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.FriendTenantId, e.FriendUserId });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>(b =>
        {
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.SubscriptionEndDateUtc });
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.CreationTime });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriptionPayment>(b =>
        {
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.Status, e.CreationTime });
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.PaymentId, e.Gateway });
        });

        modelBuilder.ConfigurePersistedGrantEntity();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you selected host project as startup project in visual studio? and have you selected the default project as the one which has dbcontext in package manager console?

Comment: Can you post the DBContext class code?

Comment: Host project is startup project, And in the package manager we select the entityframeworkcore project.

Comment: I think you not getting the connection string from the proper path in the Code

Answer (score 0):

This is an ASP Zero Angular specific issue, after we fixed that path in our folder structure, this was fixed.